# POST users import v2 internal server error

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am working on a fully automatic pipeline for my company where we automatically set up projects, add users and upload files with the different APIs on BIM360. On the stage of adding a user I get a 500 internal server error:

```
{"code":2000,"message":"no implicit conversion of String into Integer"}
```

We are using a two-legged authentication approach and as such the header looks like this:

**Authorization:** Bearer <token> (It has account:write rights)

**x-user-id:** ************ (uid of my admin account)

**Content-Type:** application/json

The request content is this:

```
@"{
  ""email"": """ + ***@********.** + @""",
  ""services"": {
            ""document_management"": {
                ""access_level"": """ + admin+ @"""
            },
            ""project_administration"": {
                ""access_level"": """ + admin+ @"""
            }
        },
  ""industry_roles"": []}";
```

I just can't quite seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Hope someone can help me.

**EDIT:** Full code for this request

```
public async static Task<HttpStatusCode> AddUserToProjectEmail(string projectId, string accountId, string accessToken, string userToAddEmail, string userPrivilege, string adminUserId)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage())
            {
                //Documentation for what to put in the Http POST: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/
                request.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
                request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v2/regions/eu/accounts/" + accountId + "/projects/" + projectId + "/users/import");

                //Make the request payload
                string jsonPayload = AddPayloadToUserAddEmail(userToAddEmail, userPrivilege);
                request.Content = new StringContent(jsonPayload);

                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                request.Headers.Add("x-user-id", adminUserId);
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                //Send request
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                return response.StatusCode;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the request payload method:

```
private static string AddPayloadToUserAddEmail(string userToAddEmail, string userPrivilege)
    {

        string payload = @"{
                          ""email"": """ + userToAddEmail + @""",
                          ""services"": {
                                    ""project_administration"": {
                                        ""access_level"": """ + userPrivilege + @"""
                                    },
                                    ""document_management"": {
                                        ""access_level"": """ + userPrivilege + @"""
                                    }
                                },
                          ""industry_roles"": []
                        }";

        return payload;
    }
```

I have checked all the IDs through the URL on BIM360, however it's not possible to check the Uid of my account I think.

**EDIT 2:** I should note that I was getting a different error before I added the x-user-id header, where it just said forbidden which makes sense. This lead me to think it had something to do with the x-user-id header, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: This seems like a backend code issue.  You'll need to include the code.

Comment: Made an edit to the post with the code.

Comment: are ```accountId```, ```projectId``` strings or integers?

Comment: They're strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be like me and forget to wrap the payload into an array as stated on the docs that it has to be. Using this as payload worked

```
@"[{
                      ""email"": """ + userToAddEmail + @""",
                      ""services"": {
                                ""project_administration"": {
                                    ""access_level"": """ + userPrivilege + @"""
                                },
                                ""document_management"": {
                                    ""access_level"": """ + userPrivilege + @"""
                                }
                            },
                      ""industry_roles"": []
                    }]";
```